# Bootstrap collapsed div not closing when clicking a new link for another toggle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a single page design, with collapsed content, for the menu. I'm not using any bootstrap menu for this collapsed content - I'm just using the ahref's for showing the content of that ahref element.

The problem is that it keeps showing the content from the recent link i just clicked.

The live site is [here](http://mediemaskinen.dk)

Be aware that only "Webdesign" and "Profil" is the links working at the moment.

the script I've tried to integrate looks something like this:

```
<script> 
$('a#home-box-blog [data-toggle=collapse]').on('click', function (e) {
$('.collapse').not($(this).data("target")).collapse('hide');
});

$('a#home-box-cultivatr [data-toggle=collapse]').on('click', function (e) {
$('.collapse').not($(this).data("target")).collapse('hide');
});
</script>
```

EDIT:
also tried this:

```
$("[data-toggle^='collapse']").on('click', function (e) {
$('.collapse').not($(this).data("target")).collapse('hide');
```

If you could figure out what I'am doing wrong to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

just use this code:

```
<script>
$('.nav a').click(function () { $(".navbar-to-collapse").collapse("hide") });
</script>
```

you can change **.nav a** and **.navbar-to-collapse** with your desired variable or add to them more variable simply by using < **,** > between each variable .

more explanation:

1. **.nav a** is the variable that you target by your click and in this example it's a **link** under a **nav** class, you can modify it to target a link using ID not class

   ```
   $('#nav a')
   ```
2. **.navbar-to-collapse** is the value for **data-target=** *".navbar-to-collapse"* and you can modify it to the data-target you use.

so a complete example (for illustrating ) should be like that:

```
<header><!-- /Navigation-Bar Container-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-to-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <i class="icon-menu"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-to-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
```

and use the script :

```
<script>
$('.nav a').click(function () { $(".navbar-to-collapse").collapse("hide") });
</script>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thank you for your reply, tho it doesn't help me out - I can't seem to figure out which variable is the one controlling my links. I've tried this:

$('.content div a').click(function () { $("#profil").collapse("hide") });

Comment: Im not sure this is the right answer, how does this close the div content which is currently open? Could you take a look at my live site which i linked to in my question. Seems like this is just for closing the collapsed menu, which is not how my site is currently set up.

Comment: try to customize it to work with your site , i locked at your site but didn't find the problem sorry.